# send params with a =render :partial in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

in my view, I use content_for to load a partial (a javascript file). I'd like to pass a rails variable into the js file. Is there a way to do this?

Right now, I have this in the view:

```
-content_for (:scroller) do
 =render :partial => '/images/public/scrollerJs'
```

What I want is something like this:

```
-content_for (:scroller) do
 =render :partial => '/images/public/scrollerJs', :params => #{@images}
```

My js file _scrollerJs.erb begins like this

```
var ScrollerObject = Class.create();
 Object.extend(ScrollerObject.prototype, {
 initialize: function() { ... }
  ...
```

Where would I pick up the param? I hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a local object called `images` in your partial, that you then manipulate. The way to pass data to that local object is like this

```
render :partial => '/images/public/scrollerJs', :images => @images
```

Comment: thank you! that makes sense. but how do I access it in my javascript file? None of the following seem to work: this.images[0] .. @images[0] .. #{@images[0]} ...

Comment: I'm on rails 2 by the way, if that makes a difference.

Comment: well your file is an erb file before becoming js, so I'd use erb with <% images.each do |image| %>var imageName = <%= image.name %>;<% end %>